# How elements are fixed by this action?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the vector space over the field $F_3$ (field with $3$ elements) of dimension $3$. Define an action of the symmetric group $S_3$ on $V$ by $\sigma.e_i$= $e_{\sigma (i)}$ where  {$e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$} is a basis for $V$. Then the cardinality of the set of vectors fixed by this action is:

1. $0$
2. $3$
3. $9$
4. $27$

I think the only vectors fixed by this action are ${(a,a,a) \ \text{for}\ a\in F_3}$. So I think the answer has to be $3$. Is there Any other vector fixed by the above action?

Comment: Step 1) Take an arbitrary vector not of that form. Step 2) Find a permutation that doesn't leave it fixed.

Comment: @Arthur There is only one vector of the form (a,b,c) and the rest are of the form (a,b,a) or (a,a,b) or (b,a,a). For last two type vectors the permutation  (1,3) serves the purpose and for the first 2 types the permutation  (1,2) serves the purpose. Am I correct.....

Comment: Well, there are six vectors of that first form, but all right. Yes, that works. Or you could just use the permutation $(1,2,3)$ on all of them.

Comment: @Arthur am sorry I missed it!!! So my answer is correct right? And thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Yes, your answer 3 is correct, and the reasoning you had in your previous comment for why there are no other vectors was correct too. Whether you, in the end, want to split into cases and use either $(1, 3)$ or $(1, 2)$ on those, like you did, or just use $(1,2,3)$, as I suggested, is entirely up to you.

Comment: How do you define $\sigma (c_1 e_1 + c_2 e_2)$?  @Arthur

Comment: How do you define $\sigma (c_1 e_1 + c_2 e_2)$?@shwetha

Comment: @cmi It's defined as $c_1e_{\sigma(1)}+c_2e_{\sigma(2)}$.

Comment: How did you know that?@Arthur

Comment: How did you know that?@Arthur

Comment: @cmi Because that's what "$\sigma.e_i=e_{\sigma (i)}$" means.

Comment: I could not under stand you...@Arthur