# Can I take the vector space generated by {$1 , x, x^2$} over the field $F_3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, group-actions

Let $V$ be the vector space over the field $F_3$ (field with $3$ elements) of dimension $3$. Define an action of the symmetric group $S_3$ on $V$ by $\sigma.e_i$= $e_{\sigma (i)}$ where  {$e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$} is a basis for $V$.

Can anyone please make me understand what this problem is saying?

I do not understand what is a vector space over the field $F_3$ (field with $3$ elements) ?
Can I  take the vector space generated by {$1 , x, x^2$} over the field $F_3$?

If the action is only on he basis elements then how would we find the operations like $ \sigma (e_1 + e_2)$?

Comment: Look up the definition of a vector space over an arbitrary field $K$ and then just take $K=\Bbb{F}_3$.

Comment: I did not get you.. Can you please go through my whole question?@DietrichBurde

Comment: I meant your statement "I do not understand what is a vector space over the field $\Bbb{F}_3$". This is just the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the action is only on he basis elements then how would we find the operations like $σ(e_1+e_2)$?

This seems to be the key to your question.

You are right: at the outset, the action is explicitly only defined on the set $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$. Given a group element $\sigma$, and one of these basis elements $b$, we know what $\sigma\cdot b$ is, and that is all.

But every mapping defined on the basis of a vector space gives rise to a *unique linear transformation* extending that mapping to the entire vector space spanned by the elements. Furthermore, if the mapping is a bijection and the vector space is finite dimensional, the extension is an isomorphism.

So what is happening is that *by definition* the action on an arbitrary element of the vector space is defined to be the linear extension: $\sigma\cdot (\sum\lambda_ie_i):=\sum\lambda_i(\sigma\cdot e_i)$.

You can check all the axioms to confirm that indeed, the originally defined group action on the basis has now been promoted to a group action of $S_3$ on the entire vector space spanned by the basis.

This "lifting" of the group action is what you were missing, I think.

---

There's another way to see how this happens. You can rephrase a group action of $G$ on a set $X$ to be a homomorphism from $G\to Sym(X)$.

If $X$ is the finite basis of an $n$ dimensional $F$ vector space, we have another group homomorphism from $Sym(X)\to GL(n,F)$. Composing these two homomorphisms we get a group homomorphism from $G\to GL(n,F)$, and that defines an action of $G$ on $span(X)$.

It says, essentially, that every element of $G$ acts like a linear automorphism on $span(X)$ (very nice elements of $Sym(span(X))$!)

Answer (score 1):

A vector space of dimension $3$ with the underlying field $F_3$ is isomorphic to $F_3^3$. A standard basis for this vector space is $\{e_1=(1,0,0)^{T},e_2=(0,1,0)^{T},e_3=(0,0,1)^{T}\}$. As we know, A linear map $f$ from the vector space to itself can be represented by a matrix of this form \begin{bmatrix}
    .       & . & . \\
    f(e_1)       &f(e_2) & f(e_3) \\
     \
    .       & .&.
\end{bmatrix}

Since a permutation just permute the basis vectors, The resulting linear maps are exactly the 3by3 permutation matrices. Foe example, the permutation $(1,2) \in S_3$ can be represented by the matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
    0      & 1 & 0 \\
    1       &0 & 0 \\
     \
    0      & 0&1
\end{bmatrix}. So you can really think of your group as the set of permutation matrices and a group element acting on the vectors by left multiply the matrix with the vector. For example, $(1,2)$ act on the vector $(1,2,2)^{T}$ gives the vector $(2,1,2)^{T}$.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of $V$ simply consist of triples of elements from $F_3$. So a typical element of $V$ would be $(1,0,2)$ or $(2,1,2)$ etc. Addition of vectors in $V$ follows the rules of addition in $F_3$ so $(1,0,2)+(2,1,2) = (0,1,1)$. Scalar multiplication of vectors follows the rules of multiplication in $F_3$, so $2(1,0,2) = (1,0,2) + (1,0,2) = (2,0,1)$.

I think there is an unstated assumption that each action $\sigma$ will be linear on $V$, so

$ \sigma(e_1 + e_2) = \sigma(e_1) + \sigma(e_2) = e_{\sigma(1)} + e_{\sigma(2)} $

Comment: So I think this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2592909/how-elements-are-fixed-by-this-action is not complete.@gandalf61

Comment: @cmi This is an answer to your question. Why do yo refer to some other question? Furthermore, the linked question seems complete to me. Why not?

Comment: Is it illegal here to refer other question?@Christoph

Comment: Can you tell me how to define $\sigma (c_1 e_1 + c_2 e_2)$?@Christoph

Comment: @cmi as multiple responders have stated, the group action should be linear on the vector space, as it can be represented that way. Therefore it splits as you expect. A Google search shows that Wolfram mathworld confirms this with a general statement about group actions I don't confess to understand, but I believe it is mathnoob's answer here.